# Table cell data overflow remove border in css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one table with three columns. If first td text overflow in second td then remove the first td right border. How to do that in css, Please help me because am search in Google, but I can't find that solution. Please see that image below (final output like this)
[image]

```
<table style="width: 350px;">
    <tr id="row1" style="width: 350px;">
        <td style="width: 100px; float: left; border: 1px solid black; white-space: nowrap; color:Red;">
            <span>First td over flow remove td right border</span>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 100px; float: left; border: 1px solid black">
            <span>Second Div</span>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 130px; float: left; border: 1px solid black">
            <span>Third Div</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2" style="width: 350px">
        <td style="width: 100px; float: left; border: 1px solid black">
            <span>First Div</span>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 100px; float: left; border: 1px solid black">
            <span>Second Div</span>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 130px; float: left; border: 1px solid black">
            <span>Third Div</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what will happen if you remove first td right border? will it looks good?

Comment: Hi Suresh, please refer my output image. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: can you provide some fiddle, to try something upon.

Comment: Do u want to do a `colspan` like `<td colspan=2 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what purpose you have created the table like this. But here is the answer for your structure. Update your first td like below.

```
<td style="width: 100px; float: left; border: 1px solid black; white-space: nowrap; color:Red; z-index:999; height:20px; position:relative;">
        <span style="background-color:#fff; position:absolute; left:2px; top:0; z-index:2;">First td over flow remove td right border</span>
</td>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4S9Ef/1/)